# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0

Tags: c#, wcf

When I use below code I'm getting the error like:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}

```
Uri tfsUri = (TFSServerURL.Length < 1) ? new 
Uri("http://100.201.011.22:8080/tfs/yuii/") : new Uri(TFSServerURL);
mObjTFSServer = new TeamFoundationServer(tfsUri, networkCredential);
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you would do a regsvr on the TFS Dlls. There should be no reason to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning,
Do you copy all dll used in debug/relase or project directory?
Can use check "Copy local" in reference properties.
It also checks if all the dlls are registered. (use command regsvr32 for register dll from command line "CMD")

Comment: Please explain in details how to register dll

Comment: i am getting this error in command promt: tdll was loaded but the dllregisterserver entry point was not found regsvr32

Comment: - Open with "run as admin"  command pront from start menu of windows (digit CMD from search bar)      - Move to directory of Dll file used in your project with command "cd.." return an up level folder or "cd YourFolderName" for open current folder           - run command "regsrv32 NameOfDllUsed.dll" and press enter [You can digit firt word and press tab for autocomplete name]      - A message of confirm appear if all ok.

Comment: open cmd with "Run As Administrator" and retry

Comment: still getting same error ; attached image on question

Comment: if you have an error and use Windows 64bit should try this: 

    -Open an elevated command prompt.
   - If the 32-bit DLL is in the %systemroot%\System32 folder, move it to the %systemroot%\SysWoW64 folder.
  -  Run the following command:

    %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 <full path of the DLL>

Comment: Try to copy dll in system32 folder or try the code write 4 minutes ago for 64bit system...

Comment: We will find a solution... :-) Is it possible that dll is damaged?

Comment: try with regasm.exe    Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool

Comment: am getting error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0

 when registering dll: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

Comment: try to run ccleaner for delete registry key  "orphaned". Try to clean and rebuild solution. I find this: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/msdn-disc-3538/microsoft-teamfoundation-client-dll/

Comment: how to delete register "orphaned" without using ccleaner?

Comment: Doing this manually is very dangerous. I use ccleaner because is more safe. You can use regedit but you must delete manually the  "orphaned" keys. It's very dangerous.

Comment: thanks, i cleaned using ccleaner but not fixed issue.

Comment: try to move in visualstudio on the explorer solution, click with right button on solution, clean solution and after rebuild

Comment: try to install it form Nuget (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.* assemblies)

Comment: Good morning rafi... Did you find the solution?

Comment: it worked when i replace DLL Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll manually, But when rebuild project the dll is changing and same as previous issue.

Comment: Changes to debug folder? If yes you can remove copy local check (It isn't a definitive solution but it is a mode to avoid the problem :-(

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much Tarma.

Comment: If I can be useful I do it gladly...  have a nice day...;-)

Answer (score 1):

i think you should replace the address (10.2.0.22) with the www.putthewebaddress here.com

Comment: i don't think that. I feel some dll missing or mismatch